# check user finger index or type

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, fingerprint

I have one application that register and verified user's fingerprint.Now I want to know which finger user try to register so, Is there anything common between all humans finger that we can identify the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of literature on the problem of finger print analysis recognition.  I suggest that you start with the Wikipedia pages on [fingerprint classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint#Classifying_fingerprints) and [fingerprint recognition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition)

A quick browse through the Wikipedia pages doesn't show any obvious way to determine that a given print is (say) for someone's pinky on their left hand.  (But then again, I'm not sure why you'd want to know that ...)

Comment: This is not an emergency or compulsory to implement but, as question  arise on my mind while developing this application i just ask.

Comment: @chetan - my gut feeling is that there is so much variability in finger sizes between men/women/children that you would not be able to tell reliably.  Anyway, if you want to know for sure, ask a real-life fingerprint expert.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there are heuristics based on for instance shapes of the print you'll never know for sure, so I wouldn't let my program logic rely on those algorithms anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to determine which finger is being used is to use a ten print fingerprint reader.  Here four fingers (or two thumbs) are captured simultaneously and the relative positions of the fingers can be used to identify the finger (Assuming that the fingers are correctly placed).